# I cannot connect through SSH to SLES15 SP4

Tags: authentication, amazon-ec2, ssh, sles

I need to setup a SLES15 SP4 instance on Amazon EC2. After being created the instance, I cannot connect to it using EC2 Instance Connect neither SSH Client.

I tried different configurations and pairing keys without success (also with no key).

I can see 22 port is open:

[image]

The users that I tried are "ec2-user" and "root".

Answer (score 0):

I think during creation of an instance the process involves specifying a username within that instance. Use `ssh -v -l that-username ip-address`.

Also provide the exact command that is used, and the exact error message.